# Generate an amount of random numbers from a paramter then store them to call in a method later

Tags: java, random

I am trying to generate random numbers the amount determined by a paramter then store these numbers so i can assign them to a uniqe id field combined with a string code before e.g user inputs code "HG-" and the number 4 the method will output HG-3981 or HG-8394 etc

My attempt

```
    {

        for (int i = 0; i == length; i++)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int rand = random.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1) + 1;

        }
        System.out.println(prefix + "-" + length);
    }
```

Comment: Change `System.out.println(prefix + "-" + length);` to `System.out.println(prefix + "-" + rand);`

Comment: There are all kinds of problems here; which ones are you asking about?

Comment: Have you tried just generating just one random number between (`Math.pow(10, length-1)` and `Math.pow(10, length)`?

Comment: i cant use rand as it was declared within the loop and the print is outside of the loop if i was to put the print in the loop would this worl

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the `length`, shouldn't you be printing the `rand` variable?

*Example:*

```
System.out.println(prefix+"-"+rand);
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: i tried this but as rand is declared within the loop it cant be called outside in the print and if i put the print into the loop nothing prints at all i also need to combine the numbers and the string into one variable once its been made cos this will then be assigned to my customerID field which is a string

Answer (score 0):

This will generate 0 padded `length` digit integers:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int length = 6;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(length);
    df.setMinimumIntegerDigits(length);
    df.setGroupingUsed(false);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        System.out.println(df.format(rand.nextInt((int)Math.pow(10,length))));
    }
```

You will have to store these in order to ensure uniqueness.

You can use any of `Set<Integer>`, `int[10^length]`, `boolean[10^length]` or `BitSet(10^lenght)` in order to record already generated numbers. Be mindful of process restarts etc.